# Spring Boot Rest Service Bean Creation Exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am getting the below exception in my Spring boot rest service Application.This exception occurs sometimes when I start the service.I am able to start the service after 4 or 5 attempts.Any solution is appreciated.

```
RuntimeException generated in Method : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory#populateBeanand exception messageError creating bean with name 'changeRecordService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.IChangeRecordAdapter com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.ChangeRecordService.iChangeRecordAdapter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'injectChangeRecordDaoAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.ChangeRecordDaoAdapter.vTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao.VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**This is my Spring Boot Main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { HypermediaAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

    private static String adapterType;

    public static String getAdapterType() {
        return adapterType;
    }

    public static void setAdapterType(String adapterType) {
        Application.adapterType = adapterType;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length != 0) {
            Application.setAdapterType(args[0]);

        } else {
            Application.setAdapterType("DAO");
        }

        try {

            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        } catch (Exception runtimeException) {
            System.out.println(
                    "RuntimeException generated in Method : " + runtimeException.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName() + "#"
                            + runtimeException.getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + "and exception message"
                            + runtimeException.getMessage());
            // Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(hook);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Tweak the connection pool used by Jetty to handle incoming HTTP
     * minThreads & maxThreads connections
     * 
     * @param port
     * @param maxThreads
     * @param minThreads
     * @param idleTimeout
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(
            @Value("${server.port}") final String port,
            @Value("${jetty.threadPool.maxThreads:200}") final String maxThreads,
            @Value("${jetty.threadPool.minThreads:50}") final String minThreads,
            @Value("${jetty.threadPool.idleTimeout:60000}") final String idleTimeout) {

        final JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(
                Integer.valueOf(port));
        factory.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {
            public void customize(Server server) {
                final QueuedThreadPool threadPool = server.getBean(QueuedThreadPool.class);
                threadPool.setMaxThreads(Integer.valueOf(maxThreads));
                threadPool.setMinThreads(Integer.valueOf(minThreads));
                threadPool.setIdleTimeout(Integer.valueOf(idleTimeout));
            }

        });
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket newsApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("changerecord").apiInfo(apiInfo()).select()
                .paths(regex("/bsi/.*")).build().directModelSubstitute(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, MixIn.class);
    }

    public static interface MixIn {
        @JsonIgnore
        public void setYear(int year);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Catalog Service REST APIs").description("Microservice REST APIs")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("http://....").contact("TechMahindra").license("TechMahindra Licensed")
                .licenseUrl("https://techmahindra.com").version("2.0").build();
    }
}
```

**This is my controller class.**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bsi/vtm/changerecord")
public class ChangeRecordController {

    @Autowired
    private ChangeRecordService changerecordService;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChangeRecordController.class);
```

**This is my service class.**

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class ChangeRecordService {
            private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChangeRecordService.class);

@Autowired
private IChangeRecordAdapter iChangeRecordAdapter;
```

**This is Change Record Impl**

```
public class ChangeRecordDaoAdapter extends IChangeRecordAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChangeRecordDaoAdapter.class);

    @Autowired
    private VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository vTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private NotificationHelper notificationHelper;  

    @Autowired
    private SearchRepository searchRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CounterRepository counterRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProducerConfiguration producerConfiguration;


    @Autowired
    private ChangeRecordRepository changerecordRepository;
```

**This is my Notification helper**

```
package com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper;

    public class NotificationHelper {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationHelper.class);
    @Autowired
    private ChangeRecordRepository changeRecordRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ImpactedGroupsSearchCriteria impactedGroupsSearchCriteria;

    @Autowired
    private TechnologiesSearchCriteria technologiesSearchCriteria;

    @Autowired
    private SearchGroupRepository searchGroupRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CbusEmailClient client;

    @Autowired
    private NotificationTrackingRepository notificationTrackingRepository;

    @Autowired
    private VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository userUpdateHistoryRepository;


    @Value("${vtm.url.service.userMgmt.getProfile}")
    private String userMgmtServiceURL;
```

**This is my InjectConfiguration**

```
package com.att.vtm.changerecord.conditionalinjection;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.approverreviewer.wrapper.ApproverReviewerDaoAdapter;
import com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.ChangeRecordDaoAdapter;
import com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.ChangeRecordMetadataDaoAdapter;
import com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.ChangeRecordReportAdapter;
import com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.ChangeRecordTaskDaoAdapter;
import com.att.vtm.changerecord.services.changerecord.wrapper.NotificationHelper;
import com.att.vtm.crjob.services.crjob.wrapper.CRJobDaoAdapter;
import com.att.vtm.crjob.services.crjob.wrapper.DeviceTestJobsDaoAdapter;


@Configuration
public class InjectionConfiguration {

    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String DB_DRIVER;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String DB_PASSWORD;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String DB_URL;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String DB_USERNAME;


  @Bean
  @Conditional(DaoCondition.class)
  public ChangeRecordDaoAdapter injectChangeRecordDaoAdapter () throws Exception{
      System.out.println("***INJECTING ChangeRecordDaoAdapter...****");
      return new ChangeRecordDaoAdapter();
  }

  @Bean
  @Conditional(DaoCondition.class)
  public ChangeRecordMetadataDaoAdapter injectChangeRecordMetadataDaoAdapter () throws Exception{
      System.out.println("***INJECTING ChangeRecordMetadataDaoAdapter...****");
      return new ChangeRecordMetadataDaoAdapter();
  }

  @Bean
  @Conditional(DaoCondition.class)
  public NotificationHelper injectNotificationHelper () throws Exception{
      System.out.println("***INJECTING NotificationHelper...****");
      return new NotificationHelper();
  }

  @Bean
  @Conditional(DaoCondition.class)
  public ChangeRecordTaskDaoAdapter injectChangeRecordTaskDaoAdapter () throws Exception{
      System.out.println("***INJECTING ChangeRecordTaskDaoAdapter...****");
      return new ChangeRecordTaskDaoAdapter();
  }

  @Bean
  @Conditional(DaoCondition.class)
  public CRJobDaoAdapter injectCRJobDaoAdapter () throws Exception{
      System.out.println("***INJECTING CRJob DAO ADAPTER...****");
      return new CRJobDaoAdapter();
  }


  @Bean
  @Conditional(DaoCondition.class)
  public DeviceTestJobsDaoAdapter injectDeviceTestJobsDaoAdapter () throws Exception{
      System.out.println("***INJECTING DeviceTestJobs DAO ADAPTER...****");
      return new DeviceTestJobsDaoAdapter();
  }

  @Bean
  @Conditional(DaoCondition.class)
  public ChangeRecordReportAdapter injectChangeRecordReportAdapter() throws Exception{
      System.out.println("***....INJECTING DeviceTestJobs DAO ADAPTER.......****");
      return new ChangeRecordReportAdapter();
  }

  @Bean
  @Conditional(DaoCondition.class)
  public ApproverReviewerDaoAdapter injectApproverReviewerDaoAdapter() throws Exception{
      System.out.println("***....INJECTING ApproverReviewerDaoAdapter.......****");
      return new ApproverReviewerDaoAdapter();
  }

  @Bean
  public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate()
  {
      System.out.println("***INJECTING get jdbcTemplate ...****");
      return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    System.out.println("***INJECTING dataSource DAO ADAPTER...****");
    System.out.println(" DriverName :"+DB_DRIVER);
    System.out.println(" DB_URL :"+DB_URL);
    System.out.println(" DB_USERNAME :"+DB_USERNAME);
    System.out.println(" DB_PASSWORD :"+DB_PASSWORD);

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
    return dataSource;
  }

 }
```

**This is My VTMRefUpdateRepository**

```
package com.att.vtm.changerecord.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;

import com.att.vtm.changerecord.dto.VTMRefUserUpdateHistory;

public interface VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository extends MongoRepository<VTMRefUserUpdateHistory, String> {
    // @Query("select * from VTMRefUserUpdateHistory a where v.ticketNo = ?1")
    @Query("{ 'ticketNo' : ?0 }")
    public List<VTMRefUserUpdateHistory> findByTicketNo(String ticketNo);

    // @Query("select * from VTMRefUserUpdateHistory a where v.pRNumber = ?1")
    @Query("{ 'pRNumber' : ?0 }")
    public List<VTMRefUserUpdateHistory> findByPRNumber(String pRNumber);

    // @Query("select * from VTMRefUserUpdateHistory a where v.cRNumber = ?1")
    @Query("{ 'cRNumber' : ?0 }")
    public List<VTMRefUserUpdateHistory> findByCRNumber(String cRNumber);


    public List<VTMRefUserUpdateHistory> findByCRNumberAndFieldNameAndNewValue(String cRNumber, String fieldName, String newValue);
}
```

Comment: Why the convoluted setup? Your application listener is actually dangerous, when spring boot shutsdown the close method is already called. So please remove it. The `ThrowExceptionIfHandlerNotFound` can be set through `application.properties` so no need to hack that. Then that removes the need to hack around with the context and that will probably also fix your issues.

Comment: Is your VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository annotated with @Repository or @Component?

Comment: I don't like the value of `@CoponentScan` annotation. I think the asterisk is messing around. Try this: `@ComponentScan("com.att.vtm")`

Answer (score 0):

You need add @Service annotation for your service.
try the following,

```
@Service
public class ChangeRecordService {
   // your code
}
```

also check your IChangeRecordAdapter class

Comment: Thanks sparrow .The service annotation is already present.I just edited my post.Any other suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is flawed, at least the `ApplicationListener` isn't needed and the properties on the the `DispatcherServlet` can simply be set through specifying it in the `application.properties`.

First add `spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true` to your `application.properties` and remove the getting and modifying of the `DispatcherServlet`.

This will reduce, for now, your `Application` class to the simple starting of the application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan("com.att.vtm.*")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {HypermediaAutoConfiguration.class}) 
@EnableCaching
@EnableMongoRepositories(value = { "com.att.vtm" })


public class Application {

  private static String adapterType;

  public static String getAdapterType(){
      return adapterType;
  }

  public static void setAdapterType(String adapterType){
      Application.adapterType = adapterType;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      if(args.length != 0){
          Application.setAdapterType(args[0]);

      }else{
          Application.setAdapterType("DAO");
      }

      try{

          SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

      }
      catch(Exception runtimeException){
           System.out.println("RuntimeException generated in Method : "+ runtimeException.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName()
                  +"#"+runtimeException.getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() 
                  +"and exception message"+runtimeException.getMessage());
           //Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(hook);  
      }    
  }

  /**
   * Tweak the connection pool used by Jetty to handle incoming HTTP minThreads & maxThreads connections
   * @param port
   * @param maxThreads
   * @param minThreads
   * @param idleTimeout
   * @return
   */
  @Bean
  public JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(@Value("${server.port}") final String port,
              @Value("${jetty.threadPool.maxThreads:200}") final String maxThreads,
              @Value("${jetty.threadPool.minThreads:50}") final String minThreads,
              @Value("${jetty.threadPool.idleTimeout:60000}") final String idleTimeout) {

              final JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory =  new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(Integer.valueOf(port));
              factory.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {
              public void customize(Server server) {
              final QueuedThreadPool threadPool = server.getBean(QueuedThreadPool.class);
              threadPool.setMaxThreads(Integer.valueOf(maxThreads));
              threadPool.setMinThreads(Integer.valueOf(minThreads));
              threadPool.setIdleTimeout(Integer.valueOf(idleTimeout));
          }

      });
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public Docket newsApi() {
      return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
              .groupName("changerecord")
              .apiInfo(apiInfo())
              .select()              
              .paths(regex("/bsi/.*"))
              .build()
              .directModelSubstitute(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, MixIn.class);
  }

  public static interface MixIn {
      @JsonIgnore
      public void setYear(int year);
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @return
   */
  private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
      return new ApiInfoBuilder()
              .title("Catalog Service REST APIs")
              .description("Microservice REST APIs")
              .termsOfServiceUrl("http://....")
              .contact("TechMahindra")
              .license("TechMahindra Licensed")
              .licenseUrl("https://techmahindra.com")
              .version("2.0")
              .build();
  }
}
```

I would also suggest to not add a `JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` but only the customizer as a bean, Spring Boot detects those and they will be applied. Just replace your `JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` with the `JettyServerCustomizer`.

```
@Bean
public JettyServerCustomizer threadPoolCustomizer(Value("${jetty.threadPool.maxThreads:200}") final Integer maxThreads,
          @Value("${jetty.threadPool.minThreads:50}") final Integer minThreads,
          @Value("${jetty.threadPool.idleTimeout:60000}") final Integer idleTimeout) {
    return new JettyServerCustomizer() {
      public void customize(Server server) {
          final QueuedThreadPool threadPool = server.getBean(QueuedThreadPool.class);
          threadPool.setMaxThreads(maxThreads);
          threadPool.setMinThreads(minThreads);
          threadPool.setIdleTimeout(idleTimeout);
      }
}
```

This will all reduce the complexity of your `Application` class.

I do believe however that the main issue here is your listener and use of statics to reference stuff. As mentioned you don't need them.

Some other things to consider, I suggest that you put the `Application` class in the `com.att.vtm` package (if it isn't already there). With that you can cleanup your annotations on the class as well.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {HypermediaAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableCaching
public class Application { ... }
```

Many of the annotations are already inmplied by `@SpringBootApplication` and I suggest to leverage that to your advantage.

**Update 1**

Your JDBC configuration could/should also be in `application.properties` rename your `db.*` properties to `spring.datasource` properties and remove the `JdbcTemplate` and `DataSource` creation from your `InjectionConfiguration` and let spring boot handle that. Then add the `@Conditional` on the class instead of on the separate `@Bean` methods.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${db.driver}
spring.datasource.url=${db.url}
spring.datasource.username=${db.username}
spring.datasource.password=${db.password}
```

*Note:* you can probably leave out the `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` as that is deduced from the `spring.datasource.url` property.

Comment: I have made changes as suggested.still getting the exception.Could you please suggest any other solution

Comment: Added some additional removals to the question and can you add your `DaoCondition` to your question.

Comment: Hello All,Could you please go through the Class NotificationHelper and ChangeRecordDaoAdapter  class.I have autowired VTMRefUserUpdateHistoryRepository in both the class as well as I have autowired NotificationHelper in ChangeRecordDaoAdapter  .Is that a issue?Is there in cyclic kind of autowring problem.Please help to resolve the issue.